# pytest 3.1.0 does not detect plugin and does not report errors about it

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, pytest, pytest-django

I've setup pytest (3.1.0) and pytest-django (3.1.2) to run some tests. This works great on Ubuntu 17.04 and OSX 10.12.2, but not on our test environment (Ubuntu 12.04.5).

When reviewing `pytest --version`, the plugin is detected on the environments where everything is working as expected, but on the test server the plugin is not listed. This results in errors like `ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.` Output for a working environment:

```
$ venv/bin/pytest --version
This is pytest version 3.1.0, imported from /home/me/code/myproject/myproject_device/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest.pyc
setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-django-3.1.2 at /home/me/code/myproject/myproject_device/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py
```

When searching for details, I'm finding a number of pytest issues (f.i. https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1307) regarding suppression of import errors for pytest plugins, but these refer to changes in behaviour for pytest 3, where errors or warnings would be visible for these kind of problems. But I don't see any error other than the ImproperlyConfigured exception from django itself. Full output:

```
$ ./vagrant_venv/bin/pytest --version
This is pytest version 3.1.0, imported from /vagrant/vagrant_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest.pyc

$ ./vagrant_venv/bin/pytest -rw -s src
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.1.0, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /vagrant, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 36 items / 1 errors 

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_________ ERROR collecting src/myproject/myproject/tests/test_views.py _________
src/myproject/myproject/tests/test_views.py:6: in <module>
    from ui.views import controlview
src/myproject/ui/views/__init__.py:2: in <module>
    from controlviewdata import ControlViewData
src/myproject/ui/views/controlviewdata.py:5: in <module>
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
vagrant_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py:1: in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware, get_token
vagrant_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py:14: in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
vagrant_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py:26: in <module>
    from django.core.cache import caches
vagrant_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py:34: in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
vagrant_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:46: in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
vagrant_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:40: in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
E   ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 7.25 seconds ============================
```

I can reproduce this in a vagrant box for `ubuntu/precise64` without issues. I tried upgrading python 2.7 to a newer version, but made no difference either.

So how do I track down the error that prevents the `pytest-django` plugin to load?